# Django App Install Script - How to add app to INSTALLED_APPS setting?

Tags: python, django, installation

I've written a Django app, and now I want to make it easy to deploy on multiple servers.

The basic installation is:

1. Copy the app folder into the Django project folder
2. Add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`
3. Run `./manage.py collectstatic`

This particular app doesn't need to use the DB, but if it did, I'd use south and run `./manage.py migrate`, but that's another story.

The part I'm having trouble with is #2. I don't want to have to manually edit this file every time. What's the easiest/most robust way to update that?

I was thinking I could use the `inspect` module to find the variable and then somehow append it, but I'm not having any luck. `inspect.getsourcelines` won't find variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your settings.py using bash.

```
#set $SETTINGS_FILE variable to full path of the your django project settings.py file
SETTINGS_FILE="/path/to/your/django/project/settings.py"
# checks that app $1 is in the django project settings file
is_app_in_django_settings() {
    # checking that django project settings file exists
    if [ ! -f $SETTINGS_FILE ]; then
        echo "Error: The django project settings file '$SETTINGS_FILE' does not exist"
        exit 1
    fi
    cat $SETTINGS_FILE | grep -Pzo "INSTALLED_APPS\s?=\s?\[[\s\w\.,']*$1[\s\w\.,']*\]\n?" > /dev/null 2>&1
    # now $?=0 if app is in settings file
    # $? not 0 otherwise
}

# adds app $1 to the django project settings
add_app2django_settings() {
    is_app_in_django_settings $1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Info. The app '$1' is not in the django project settings file '$SETTINGS_FILE'. Adding."
        sed -i -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -re "s/(INSTALLED_APPS\s?=\s?\[[\n '._a-zA-Z,]*)/\1    '$1',\n/g" $SETTINGS_FILE
        # checking that app $1 successfully added to django project settings file
        is_app_in_django_settings $1
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Error. Could not add the app '$1' to the django project settings file '$SETTINGS_FILE'. Add it manually, then run this script again."
            exit 1
        else
            echo "Info. The app '$1' was successfully added to the django settings file '$SETTINGS_FILE'."
        fi
    else
        echo "Info. The app '$1' is already in the django project settings file '$SETTINGS_FILE'"
    fi
}
```

Use:

```
add_app2django_settings "my_app"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are my reasons why I think this would be wrong:

- it is extra code complexity without any big need, adding one line to settings every time is not that bad, especially if you are doing step #1 and #3.
- it will become not explicit what apps your project is using. When another developer will  work on your project, he might not know that your app is installed.
- you should do step #1 and step #2 on code versioning system, test the whole system and then commit the changes and just then deploy it.

I think you have something wrong (from my point of view) in your develop/deploy process if you are looking for such an "optimization". I think it is much easier and better to use `INSTALLED_APPS`.

If you are building something for public use and you want to make it as easy as possible to add modules then it would be nice. In this case I would recommend to package project and it's apps as python eggs and make use of entry points. Then you could deploy an app into project like this:

```
pip install my-app-name
```

Without even step #1 and #3! Step #1 will be done by `pip`, and step #2 and #3 will be done by setup hooks defined in your project.

[Paste script](http://pythonpaste.org/script/) is a good example of entry-points utilization:

```
# Install paste script:
pip install pastescript

# install django templates for pastescript:
pip install fez.djangoskel

# now paste script knows about fez.djangoskel because of entry-points

# start a new django project from fez's templates:
paste create -t django_buildout
```

Here is a portion of `setup.py` from fez.djangoskel package:

```
...
entry_points="""
[paste.paster_create_template]
django_buildout=fez.djangoskel.pastertemplates:DjangoBuildoutTemplate
django_app=fez.djangoskel.pastertemplates:DjangoAppTemplate
...
```

[zc.buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) is another great tool which might make your deployments much easier. Python eggs plays very nice with buildout.

Comment: (1) It's not just 1 line actually. It's a few lines in a different places. I could use the same methodology to do all of them. 1 and 3 won't be done by hand, they'll be automated too. (2) Why wouldn't be explicit? The script would explicitly add it to INSTALLED_APPS. Any developer could see the update by looking at settings.py. (3) Can't. This is an add-on; settings.py might change in other ways that I don't want to touch, so version-controlling it won't work. For the same reason, PIP won't work. I don't have a static settings.py file that I can insert hooks into.--

Comment: -- because settings.py is maintained by a 3rd party.

Comment: @Mark, You can have your own settings file which is tracked and use `from client_settings import *` to load third-party settings. You could then modify the INSTALLED_APPS attribute dynamically.

Comment: I could.... and I guess I could inject that line of code at the bottom of the file pretty easily too. Not a bad idea, but not quite as clean as having 1 file. Can you imagine if all the plugins did this?

Comment: You would only have 2 settings files: `default-settings` - tracked in CVS with really important settings; `local-settings` - for your client specific needs. This approach is cleaner than keeping all settings in non-tracked file. In your `default-settings` file you could implement your search for available modules in system path and if you find something you can append an app to `INSTALLED_APPS`. I also think that injecting extra python code to `settings.py` from your script is one of the worst things, there are many things which can go wrong with this approach.

Comment: A lot of programs edit config files for you. WAMPSERVER for example edits all kinds of config files. As long as it's done in a robust way, I don't see what the problem is. And if it does screw up and create a syntax error, you'll know immediately. The goal is here is to avoid any kind of hand-editing. Just run the install script, and it'll install the app.